# I'm trying to display the winning array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to display the winning array after the if and elsif statements but i don't know how to properly display the array that has been chosen to be winner after it has been checked by the if and elsif statements.

```
   # Helper Method
    def position_taken?(board, index)
   !(board[index].nil? || board[index] == " ")
   end


 # Define your WIN_COMBINATIONS constant
 WIN_COMBINATIONS = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8],
    [0,3,6],
    [1,4,7],
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8],
    [2,4,6]
   ]
#board = [" ", "X", "O"]
def won?(board)
WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |win_combination|

win_index_1 = win_combination[0]
position_1 = board[win_index_1]

win_index_2 = win_combination[1]
position_2 = board[win_index_2]

win_index_3 = win_combination[2]
position_3 = board[win_index_3]
#is position 1, 2 , and 3 all equal to X or O?
#if so return win_combination
if    position_1 == "X" && position_2 == "X"  && position_3 == "X"
  win_combination 
elsif position_1 == "O" && position_2 == "O" && position_3 == "O"
  win_combination 
  else
    false
   end
 end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
def won?(board)
  winner = nil
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.each do |win_combination|
    win_index_1 = win_combination[0]
    position_1 = board[win_index_1]

    win_index_2 = win_combination[1]
    position_2 = board[win_index_2]

    win_index_3 = win_combination[2]
    position_3 = board[win_index_3]

    if position_1 == "X" && position_2 == "X"  && position_3 == "X"
      winner = win_combination
    elsif position_1 == "O" && position_2 == "O" && position_3 == "O"
      winner = win_combination 
    end

    break if winner
  end

  return winner
end
```

Comment: Is there also a way to show false if there is an empty board?

Comment: You can just do `return false if board.blank?` in first line inside `won?` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def won?(board)
  WIN_COMBINATIONS.detect do |win_combination|
    [[?X], [?O]].include? win_combination.map(&board.method(:[])).uniq
  end
end
```

While this code might look a bit cryptic for a newbie, it’s rather clean and transparent. What we do here:

1. use [`Enumerable#detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) to detect a winner combination.
2. To check a condition, we subsequently:

   1. `Array#map` current win combination to board (this is what your six lines `win_index_N = ...` basically do;
   2. In the resulting array, we get the unique items, the result would be either `'O'` or `'X'` if and only all three symbols are the same.

Comment: Thanks again for this much a appreciated! I will check this out

Comment: would this account for an empty board as well noted by " "?

Comment: Argh, yes, good catch. I will update an answer in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Oh if all the winning combinations detected return 1 then can a following if statement go like this?

Comment: if winning_combination == 1
return winning_combination
else 
   false
end

Comment: In your original code you returned either `win_combination` itself (success,) or `false`. My code returns the same, save for it returns `nil` for not found, but in ruby `nil` and `false` have absolutely same boolean meaning, both treated as `falsey`. You do not need to patch this code. _Whether you want to return `true` / `false` instead_, use `any?` instead of `detect`.

Comment: awesome thanks so much! My tests want me to reproduce a falsey  when the board is empty. I'll try to make the necessary changes using the any? method. Thanks again for timely help. I'm still very new to programming may i still come to you if i have a few questions?